# How to acrhive specific artifacts in Jenkins recursively, while excluding a subdirectory?

Tags: jenkins

My file tree is as follows:

> Jenkins > workspace > <JOB_NAME> > out > <BUILD_NAME> /

In the <BUILD_NAME> directory, there are a bunch of files of differing extensions, such as .hex, .map and .zip. Additionally, there is another subdirectory - build. I want to archive all individual files, but not the contents of build/. What is the most efficient way to do this in a declarative pipeline? Keep in mind that the name of <BUILD_NAME> changes constantly, so it can't be hardcoded into the archive path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to archive the artifacts with `archiveArtifacts` step. The step provides option for excluding files from archiving.[1]

```
archiveArtifacts artifacts: '${JOB_NAME}/out/${BUILD_NAME}/*', excludes: '${JOB_NAME}/out/${BUILD_NAME}/build/*'
```

I assume that `BUILD_NAME` is a variable or parameter you defined, since it is not a global variable. See [2] for global variables.

[1] https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/core/#archiveartifacts-archive-the-artifacts 
[2] https://opensource.triology.de/jenkins/pipeline-syntax/globals